# React Native : Making non-editable text box long clickable to show custom context Menu

Tags: android, react-redux, react-native, react-native-paper

I am working on React Native project. That has some non-editable TextInput box, I want the functionality that when user long press in any of them it should show a menu or pop-up with option to enable the editing in the text box.

I have found some menu libraries for that but they are not working as expected. I also try the react-native-paper menu, but the problem is that I have to put my code under the Menu that is useless. Is there any way to use it in better way, like on long press I just call a function and it should show the menu.

Current code is:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { Button, Menu, Divider, Provider } from 'react-native-paper';

const MyComponent = () => {
  const [visible, setVisible] = React.useState(false);

  const openMenu = () => setVisible(true);

  const closeMenu = () => setVisible(false);

  return (
    <Provider>
      <View
        style={{
          paddingTop: 50,
          flexDirection: 'row',
          justifyContent: 'center',
        }}>
        <Menu
          visible={visible}
          onDismiss={closeMenu}
          // I have to put my all code here, in the anchor to show menu
          anchor={<Button onPress={openMenu}>Show menu</Button>}>
          <Menu.Item onPress={() => {}} title="Item 1" />
          <Menu.Item onPress={() => {}} title="Item 2" />
          <Divider />
          <Menu.Item onPress={() => {}} title="Item 3" />
        </Menu>
      </View>
    </Provider>
  );
};
```

Is there any clean way to do it, I am new to react and I can't understand what is happening, how to manage it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Library "react-native-popup-menu".
This worked for me

```
         <Menu>
            <MenuTrigger>
              ///You can Pass Text Here on which user will click
            </MenuTrigger>
            <MenuOptions customStyles={optionsStyles}>
              //Here you can Pass options that you want to include
              <MenuOption onSelect={() => onPressService(item)} text="Edit" />
              <MenuOption
                onSelect={() => DeleteProduct(item)}
                text="Delete"
              />
            </MenuOptions>
          </Menu>
```

Don't forget to provide Provider

```
  <MenuProvider>
<ScreenName {...props} />
 </MenuProvider>
```